# How can I get path from vim-rooter's function and add it to another path VIM

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
let $ROOTPATH=FindRootDirectory()
nnoremap <leader>ct :!clear<CR>:!$ROOTPATH/app/Console/cake test %:p<CR>
```

Is there a way I can write this in one line?

Using [vim-rooter pluguin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-rooter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap <leader>ct :exe "!clear; ".FindRootDirectory()."/app/Console/cake test %:p"<CR>
```

The key is the `:exe` command, which executes its argument strings. In this case there is one argument string, which is the concatenation (`.` operator) of "!clear; ", the output of the FindRootDirectory() function, and "/app/Console/cake test %:p". The `<CR>` terminates the mapping. I transformed the two shell commands into one, but you can use two commands if you prefer. See

```
:help :exe
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @garyjohn's answer is to use a map expression, i.e.

```
nnoremap <expr><leader>ct ':!clear<cr>:!' .
  \ FindRootDirectory() . '/app/Console/cake test ' . expand('%:p') . '<cr>'
```

With the `<expr>` keyword for the mapping, the right-hand side is evaluated and it's result will be used as the mapping. In this case, the result is the concatanated string. See `:h map-expression` for more details.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. It does work perfectly. Sorry for not accepting you answer. Learn a lot. Again, thank you man.

Comment: No problem, you can only mark one answer as accepted. Which answer you prefer is of course up to you. I just wanted to show a different way of solving the same problem, and I think both solutions are relatively equivalent.